# Highcharts Export as SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, export

I want to export Highcharts chart from a web page. The page enables export in two formats: JPEG and PNG using a button attached to the chart.

I want to get better quality so I want to export the chart as SVG.

Is that possible using DevTools consol for example? or any better idea?

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: see this fiddle, you have to include export.js and get native svg export support http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: @ewolden I am not the owner of the webpage I'm an end-user

Comment: @KresimirPendic should I use this code in the console ?